# How to implement a table with 2 columns for iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, user-interface, ipad

Does anyone know what is the best way to implement such UI:
[image: a table with 2 columns]

I need to have a table with 2 columns. Do I use 2 table views or collection view? Which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to reproduce this layout is to use a collection way. Managing the cell size you can obtain two columns